# Angular 6 routing with asterisk

Tags: angular, url, routes

At the moment I have a simple angular 6 project. In the app-routing module I have just configured the routes as asterisks to point on my own CmsComponent.

app.routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CmsComponent } from './cms/cms.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '**', component: CmsComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

In the html section, this is basically what I have:

```
  <div class="banner">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let nav of navItems"><a routerLink="{{nav.url}}">{{nav.title}}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div><!-- banner -->
```

But when I click on a link, the content is not updating smoothly, only on hard-refresh. I guess this has something to do with the asterisks in the Route paths?

Because when I change the paths from ** to static titles/urls it all works fine.

I have tried pushing url's to the routes, but I would rather look for something to work with **. What would the best approach be?

Comment: you need to make another router according to your rounterlink in your route file.

Comment: path: '**' is for when the app has a 404 error code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define in your routes variable all the value of nav.url. Something like this.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch:'full' }
];
```